# How to use virtualbox in a Windows 10 azure virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I've been reading about it, and I don't know if there is anyway of doing it.

I want to create a Virtualbox virtual machine inside another virtual machine I created in azure, and I don't have Hyper-V activated.

My virtual machine doesn't have a BIOS to access and enable it, and I read that not all virtual machines in azure allow nested virtualization.

The virtual machine I have right now is a B1ms standard and what I read is that I need a V3 machine to virtualize a virtual machine inside  the azure one. Is that true? I don't want to spend money just creating it and then not beeing able to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [Nested virtualization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/) in Azure. And yes you heard it right that not all Azure Virtual Machines in Azure allow this and you would need V3 VMs. Make sure to choose a VM size large enough to support the demands of a guest virtual machine.
For costing, you can either create a [trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/) Azure account that would give you a credit of $200. Or if you have got a Visual studio Pro or Enterprise license, you are eligible for [free monthly credits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/) that you can use for exploring Azure.

Comment: Can you give more details on how to achieve this? The link is just the general documentation and doesn't really explain how to use it with VirtualBox.

Comment: @Alex  - This should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use [Nested Virtualization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/) it might be better to just convert your [VirtualBox images to Azure VHDs](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/04/05/migrating-virtualbox-vdi-virtual-machines-to-azure/). This is relatively straightforward:

```sh
vboxmanage clonehd SOMETHING.vdi SOMETHING.vhd --format VHD
```

Afterwards you can use Azure Storage Explorer (or the CLI) to upload the VHD and use this to deploy a Native Virtual Machine on Azure.

Comment: thanks, but I need to run vagrant, and the vagrantfile has some specifications for a virtualbox machine and I think is not possible for me to do it as you say, and maybe some data is lost

Comment: You could use [vagrant-azure](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure) with minimal changes.